# LinkedIn New API - Can't Get r_network Permission

Tags: linkedin-api

I inherited a program that was written with the old LinkedIn API, and I'm trying to migrate it to the new API. When I try to get the `r_basicprofile` permission, my oauth token works. However, when I try `r_network` or `rw_nus`, I get a response

> invalid scope -- your application has not been authorized for
>   r_network.

Yet, when I go to `www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/xxxx/auth`, the boxes for `r_network` and `rw_nus` are checked.

I.e., A request to

> `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxx&scope=r_basicprofile&state=yyyy&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkalatublog.com%2Fwp-content%2Fmu-plugins%2Fimb-en%2Fhelpers%2Fsocial-connect%2Fapi%2Ffinalize.php%3Fapi%3Dlinkedin%26ch%zzzzz`

works, but a request to

> `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxx&scope=r_network&state=yyyy&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkalatublog.com%2Fwp-content%2Fmu-plugins%2Fimb-en%2Fhelpers%2Fsocial-connect%2Fapi%2Ffinalize.php%3Fapi%3Dlinkedin%26ch%zzzzz`

gives that error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

[As of May 15](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition#troubleshooting),

> After the grace period expires, several REST API endpoints will no longer be available for general use.  The following endpoints are the only ones that will remain available for use:

```
Profile API — /v1/people/~ `
Share API — /v1/people/~/shares 
Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}
```

> If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g. Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search, etc.) you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of the endpoints that are not listed above.

---

It looks like linkedin no longer wants to share anything with their API. Creating a new app indicates that the only possible options are `r_basicprofile`, `r_emailaddress`, `rw_company_admin`, and `w_share`:

[image]

**TLDR: they have locked down the API and restricted the usage to an extremely limited set of access points.**

Comment: What confused me is that I have an app that was created under the old system.  It's displaying checkboxes for the permissions I can no longer use.  Also, all the features my employer's website was using are no longer available.  They're having a hard time understanding that LinkedIn no longer offers that information.

Comment: I know, it seems rather heavy-handed to me too (and poorly rolled out, I had to create a new app to show the reduced permissions). It looks like you can restore some of the functionally by becoming a partner and paying them money. The era of smaller innovation for this API is over, it looks like they only want bigger players in the game.

Comment: One also needs to explicit turn off any permissions you previously had access to, but no longer do, otherwise you'll get a 401 response, even if you don't ask for those permissions.  It'd really badly-handled

Answer (score 5):

I did some more digging.  The linkedin website is misleading.  On my app linkedin page, it says that I'm approved for rw_nus and r_network, but on this page

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

it says those are no longer approved.

So the app home page in linkedin incorrectly said I had those permissions.

Comment: This explicitly mentions this access point
https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition#troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

Heres the link if you want to Apply for Linkedin 
https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr

Comment: Actually, we're looking to load the user's profile information on our site.