# Linkedin Api: Get Groups I am a Member Of

Tags: javascript, api, sdk, linkedin-api

I want to get all the groups I'm memeber of the linkedin API. I use [JavaScript SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk) for this:

```
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key:   77iju32v9t2i18
  onLoad:    onLinkedInLoad
  authorize: true   
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">     
// Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
function onLinkedInLoad() { 
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getGroupsData);
}  
function onSuccessGroup(data) {
    console.log(data);
} 
function onError(error) {
    console.dir(error);     
}

// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
function getGroupsData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name))?membership-state=member").result(onSuccessGroup).error(onError);
}
```

In the last function `getGroupsData()` I queried the url: "/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name))?membership-state=member" from [here](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#membergroups) but it issued the error:

`XHR finished loading: GET "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name))?membership-state=member"`

`errorCode: 0
  message: "Access to group-memberships denied"
  requestId: "BEVJ2X6T7J"
  status: 403
  timestamp: 1434439902873
  __proto__: Object`

What's missing, how to configure request group url?

Answer (score 1):

According to the new developer program

> If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g.
>   Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search, etc.) you
>   will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program
>   that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of
>   the endpoints that are not listed above.

More info: https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition#troubleshooting

Comment: why then I was able to retrieve my profile info thru: `function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}` ?

Comment: @almudenari, I've found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30364596/1230477) to give me more info in this line.