# Linkedin get connection's emails list PHP

Tags: php, email, connection, linkedin-api

I wants to get email list of all connections from LinkedIn...currently permission are "r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress,rw_company_admin,w_share".

Please share me any REST API or XML

I'm currently getting only my self emailaddress. I wants to fetch all email emailaddress of my connections.

Comment: not resolved still now.

Answer (score 0):

You need the **r_network** permission. This permission requires a special request to LinkedIn.

Take a look here [LinkedIn New API - Can't Get r_network Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241229/linkedin-new-api-cant-get-r-network-permission)

Comment: Still not working, Let me know me the steps to activation it ?

Comment: Can't your read the link i posted ? Everything is explained about your issue.